# PHP Get and POST data

Tags: php, html

How to I get the input id of selected button, and post it from next php page? I have this code inside my form it's dynamically populate from my database.

```
<?php 
 include('connection.php');
 $query = "Select * from tblproduct where categoryID = 1 and statusProd = 1";
 $result = $conn->query($query);
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  
      $id=$row["ID"];           
      $product=$row["product"]; 
      $image=$row["images"]; 
      echo '
       <div class="col-sm-4 divProduct" style="outline: none;background-color: transparent;border:none;height:320px;width:300px">
        <div class="content">
        <input type="submit" name="btnGame"  id="btnGame"  class="btnSubmit" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="prodID" value="'.$id.'">
        <div class="btnBuyBuy text-center">
        <img src="'.$image.'" class="imgProd" style="width:200px;height:170px;">
        <br><br>    
        <label class="nameProd">'.$product.'</label>
        <br><br>
        <div class="divBuy2">
        <label class="lblBuy">BUY NOW</label>
        </div>
    </div>  
    </div>
    </div>';
    }
}
```

And here's my code to the next page where the id displaying.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['btnGame'])) {
    $id = $_POST['prodID'];
    echo "$id";
}
else{
    echo "failed";
}
```

And the output is the last id from my `tblproduct` which is 13. How can I get the id of selected button?

Comment: @vicbyte — (a) I don't see how that page helps with this problem at all (b) W3Schools is awful and should be generally avoided. (In this case it has code examples with XSS security holes and no warnings).

Comment: @vicbyte — You don't seem to have finished reading the question. Look at the code in it (which already does everything that page talks about). Look at the last sentence of it which describes the specific problem.

Comment: It's a terrible question with a billion duplicates and possible solutions. A link to any tutorial and closing the question would be the way to go, IMO.

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> <input type="submit" name="btnGame"  id="btnGame"  class="btnSubmit" value="">
> <input type="hidden" name="prodID" value="'.$id.'">
> ```

You aren't trying to get the "id" (you mean value) of the *button*, you are trying to get the value of the hidden input next to it.

The problem with this is that proximity to the clicked submit button means nothing. All hidden inputs will be successful controls. All will be submitted to the server. Since they all share the same name, only one of them will show up in `$_POST`. (If you renamed them so the name ended in `[]` then they would **all** should up as an array and you still couldn't tell which was selected).

**Don't use a hidden input for this**.

If you care about the button that is used, then make use of the submit button.

Only the submit button used to submit the form will be successful, so its name and value can be used to tell which one was clicked.

```
<input type="submit" name="btnGame" id="btnGame"  class="btnSubmit" value="$id">
```

… and then look at `$_POST['btnGame']` instead of `$_POST['prodID']`.

---

Given that you have `value=""` I'm guessing that you don't want any text displayed on the image and that you are using CSS background image to display something in it.

Obviously, the above won't be compatible with this, so use a `<button>` element instead.

That allows you to have a different label and value.

It also allows you to put elements inside the label, so you can use a content image with an alt attribute instead of a background image and score a big accessibility win.

```
<button name="btnGame" id="btnGame" class="btnSubmit" value="$id">
    <img src="/path/to/icon.png" alt="Select product number $id">
</button>
```

Comment: Big thanks to you bro! it works. Thanks for the new knowledge!